# How to display GAE Query object contents and structure?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I want to print out the structure of a Query object, similar to how you can print out the contents of a dict or list at the interactive python prompt. I've found I'm having trouble visualizing what the data structures look like, which of course makes passing in template arguments much harder.

For example, here is a very simple UserProfile db class, and me attempting to print out all profiles, and the contents of the second profile.

```
from google.appengine.ext import db
from google.appengine.ext import webapp
from google.appengine.api import users
from google.appengine.ext.webapp.util import run_wsgi_app

class UserProfile(db.Model):
    user = db.UserProperty(auto_current_user_add=True)
    name = db.StringProperty()

class TestHandlerBasic(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        profiles = UserProfile.all()
        self.response.out.write('The whole profiles: ')
        self.response.out.write(profiles)
        self.response.out.write('<p>')
        self.response.out.write('Now, print out all profiles: <p>')
        for profile in profiles:
            self.response.out.write(profile.user)
            self.response.out.write('<br>')
        self.response.out.write('<p>')
        self.response.out.write('There are this many profiles: ')
        self.response.out.write(profiles.count())
        self.response.out.write('<p>This is the second profile profiles[1]: ')
        self.response.out.write(profiles[1])
        return

application = webapp.WSGIApplication([(r'/testbasic', TestHandlerBasic),] debug=True)
```

I get this kind of output:

> The whole profiles:
>
> Now, print out all profiles:
>
> test@example.com
>   ard@example.com
>
> There are this many profiles: 2
>
> This is the second profile profiles[1]:

After the first line I get `<google.appengine.ext.db.Query object at 0x490bd10>` and the last line I get `<models.UserProfile object at 0x490bb90>`, as well. So, how do I print out a dump of the Query object or models object?

Comment: I'm working through Chris's `BaseModel` reference to see how exactly I can merge that into what I've done. Also, http://svn.assembla.com/svn/swewi_javaprograms/swenglish/swewi/common/appenginepatch/appenginepatcher/patch.py has some monkey patching and a `__repr__` example I need to plow through.

Answer (score 3):

Query objects don't themselves hold any db.Model entities they are returned by `get()` or `fetch()`. So you would have to to switch `UserProfile.all()` for something like:

```
profiles = UserProfile.all().fetch(1000)
```

Personally I like to subclass the db.Model class and add a few conveniences for serialising my models. I do this mainly so I can get quick JSON representations of entities, but it's quite handy for dumping/inspecting them too.

Here's an example of my [BaseModel](https://gist.github.com/881913) extension that adds `__dict__` and `__json__` methods to entities. If you also added an `__repr__` that dumps the `__dict__` method you could improve the string representation of the entities when they are printed to the console.

Comment: Using a list comprehension there is needlessly complicated - `fetch` already returns a list!

Comment: I'm getting much closer to making a __repr__ to dump the dict. A simple breakthrough I've had is that in the interactive console `dir(profiles)` doesn't print out anything, but `print dir(profiles)` does.

Comment: For the life of me I haven't been able to get the `__dict__` into a `__repr__`. I can pull out the keys just fine with things like `profiles[0].properties().items()`, but the values never resolve, they are just the `<google.appengine.ext.db.IMProperty object at 0x48f96d0>` type. I did use `.fetch(100)` so I think the data should have pulled in. Any other hints for the `__repr__`?