# How to JSON encode Entities?

Tags: python, ajax, json, google-app-engine

I'm getting started with Google App Engine. I want to make AJAX chat like Twitter.

```
class ChatMessage(db.Model):
  message = db.StringProperty()
  created = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now=True)
```

Server JSON encodes the response,

```
class RPCHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
  def get(self):
    chat_list = {'message':'Hello!'}
    self.response.out.write(simplejson.dumps(chat_list))
```

Result: Hello!

This is OK. But replace RPCHandler

```
class RPCHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
  def get(self):
    newchat = ChatMessage(message="Hi!")
    newchat.put()
    que = db.Query(ChatMessage).order('-created')
    chat_list = que.fetch(limit=1)

    self.response.out.write(simplejson.dumps(chat_list))
```

Result: Error. The server is not accessible (get)

How can I JSON encode Entities?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In App Engine Python you can use this script to encode db.Models to JSON.  You may have to customize some parts, like the DateTime formatting.

http://code.google.com/p/google-app-engine-samples/source/browse/trunk/geochat/json.py?r=55

Comment: handy, I'd not spotted that before

Comment: The best part is that it looks for a __json__() method on objects, so if you have special case encoding you can add it there.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use simplejson.dumps() on a list of db.Model items directly.

See my [answer for extending db.Model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5393892/how-to-display-gae-query-object-contents-and-structure/5397072#5397072) with some handy methods for serialising db.Model instances

Answer (score 0):

I use [gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) for GAE/J. You can give it an object (or in your case, extract stuff from a result-set) and get a JSON string.

Answer (score 0):

Check the error log for the app engine.  It will tell you what error it is experiencing.  Probably you are trying to encode a Python type that json it not familiar with.  JSON will only do simple stuff like lists and dictionaries.  You can't use it for complex, custom types.