# How to JSON encode?

Tags: python, json, google-app-engine

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to JSON encode Entities?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5397793/how-to-json-encode-entities)

I'm getting started with Google App Engine. I want to make AJAX chat like Twitter.

```
class ChatMessage(db.Model):
  message = db.StringProperty()
  created = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now=True)
```

Server JSON encodes the response,

```
class RPCHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
  def get(self):
    chat_list = {'message':'Hello!'}
    self.response.out.write(simplejson.dumps(chat_list))
```

Result: Hello!

This is OK. But replace RPCHandler

```
class RPCHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
  def get(self):
    newchat = ChatMessage(message="Hi!")
    newchat.put()
    que = db.Query(ChatMessage).order('-created')
    chat_list = que.fetch(limit=1)

    self.response.out.write(simplejson.dumps(chat_list))
```

Result: Error. The server is not accessible (get)

How can I JSON encode the data from database?

Comment: This is a dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5397793/how-to-json-encode-entities

Answer (score 0):

See the Python documentation:

http://docs.python.org/library/json.html

(Specifically, look at the API method 'json.dump')

Answer (score 0):

Python has a module called `json` which can automatically serialize and deserialize dictionaries, lists, and other native Python objects (or complex types if you provide the interface).

If you can return the result of your database query as a dictionary, then you can simply use:

```
import json
as_json = json.dumps(dictionary)
```

For further reference, please visit the official [json module documentatio](http://docs.python.org/library/json.html)n.

Answer (score 0):

You should really look the way Djano handles it in its  [django.core.serializers.json](http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/core/serializers/json.py) module.